# What would be the best method to migrate Oracle database to MS Access using Java?

Tags: java, oracle, ms-access, jdbc, data-migration

This might be a very basic question, but I could use some help with this from the experts here at StackOverflow.

I am just brainstorming and weighing all the options available. So, I do not need help with the code, please. But, some suggestions or ideas would help.

Here's what I thought might work:

1. Making a d/b connection to Oracle using JDBC
2. Running SQL statements to fetch data from Oracle
3. Storing the data obtained in a data-structure
4. Making a d/b connection to MS Access using the JDBC-ODBC bridge driver
5. Creating a new d/b in Access and inseting into it using SQL
6. Closing the connections

Is there an easier or more efficient way to do this?

Another thing, this process needs to be done for several clients and each table in a d/b has millions of records. Doing this process manually would take a lot of time and so it's not such a feasible option.

OK, I hate to make this complicated. But, after importing data from Oracle, we are manipulating the data using Java code. So, after the data-transformation, we then want to migrate it to MS Access and send it to the client's way.

I really appreciate your time and help.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why do you want to switch to MS Access???

Comment: Yep, I am wildly curious too. Linked tables I could understand, but migrate seems very strange indeed.

Comment: @ Stas, pretty big. We have millions and millions of records, seriously!

Comment: @Puce, our clients are not so technical (old-fashioned maybe) and hence their requirement specifies the need for MS Access. I would stay away from MS as much as I could, but gotta do my job!

Comment: @Remou, please refer to the previous comment.

Comment: @Joachim, I don't understand why you would edit my question.

Comment: @Java_nuB: I edited it to fix the formatting of the enumeration. Editing is an [important part of stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing), it's not a hostile act.

Comment: @Joachim, thanks, no complaints from here on!

Comment: I don't think it's wise to migrate "millions and millions of records" to MS Access backend. I strongly recommend you migrate this to MS SQL Server 2008 Express instead. I realize that this doesn't answer the original question but I can't help but feel a little dismay at the idea of moving so much data to a database that is best used for 100,000 records or less (per table).

Comment: @HK1, I might have confused you by saying millions and millions of records, but I meant in the database. However, Access has enough capacity to hold the amount of data we are extracting, which is close to 100k records per table. Again, not a choice I could make, with the clients' limitations. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see why writing a java-program for this would be easier than doing it manually.

I would dump the oracle tables to disk, them import them to MS Access. Perhaps MS Access own import feature (File -> Get external data) might be useful for an ODBC import.

You could even try one of the (although non-free) tools [1](http://www.pdf-to-html-word.com/databaseconverter/oracle-to-access.htm),[2](http://www.convert-in.com/ora2acc.htm) which claims to do this for you.

Comment: Yeap, keep it simple simon.  Export to text in Oracle, import the text files with Access.

Comment: @Johan, thank you for your suggestion. But, I specifically mentioned Java because I want to build my Java skills. I find Java extremely interesting and want to understand it's capabilities.

Comment: I don't think SQL is a relevant feature for java anymore. There exist frameworks for database access (e.g., hibernate), however I wouldn't use them for this particular scenario; hence making this project perhaps not the ideal learning use case ;)

Comment: Don't sweat it, I think your 6-step usecase is sound if you prefer it that way! Another alternative is automating the manual process using a bat/batch script.

Comment: @Johan, that seems like a very good option. That would make it much simpler.

Comment: Hello @JohanSjöberg, I also have same requirement but here we need to extract data from only 20-25 tables with joins. I mean we need to extract all ~25 tables with foreign key relations so that in future related data can be extracted by client.  Please suggest if exporting data into text will also export the relationship